# How can we give condition if image is already in database and do not update again?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

code:

```
if($_FILES['logo']['name']!='')
{
    echo "<label for='Category_category_active' class='required'>University Logo</label>
           <input type='file' name='logo'  id='logoo'><span style='color:red;' disabled>Current Logo:</span>&nbsp;".$logo."";
}
else
{
    echo "<label for='Category_category_active' class='required'>University Logo</label>
          <input type='file' name='logo'  id='logoo'><span style='color:red;' disabled>Current Logo:</span>&nbsp;".$logo."";
}
if($_FILES['uni_image']['name']!='')
{
    echo "<label for='Category_category_active' class='required'>University Image</label>
          <input type='file' name='uni_image'  id='uni_image'><span style='color:red;' disabled>Current Image:</span>&nbsp; ".$uni_image."";
}
else
{
    echo "<label for='Category_category_active' class='required'>University Image</label>
          <input type='file' name='uni_image'  id='uni_image'><span style='color:red;' disabled>Current Image:</span>&nbsp; ".$uni_image."";
}
```

When I click on submit button file image name doesn't show. So how do I check if file image name is already in the database which can't be updated.

Comment: your question is not clear. please make it understandable.

Comment: `when I click on submit button file image name doesn't show` - you'll have to show your client side code - that's server side code

Answer (score 0):

Process your logic.

Try to break your steps down into easy direct steps.

You're trying to Update an Image only under the condition if it doesnt exist.

Step 1.)
On Post, Query Database for POST results `value`. Do a (this example pdo)

```
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM DatabaseTableNameHere WHERE img_column_name = ?";
        $q= $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $q->execute(array($postvarvaluetovalidate));
        $data = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Step 2. )

`if ($q->rowCount() > 0) { $error = 'msghere'; } else { continue insert into database code here }`